# What is the word for writing prose under self-imposed restrictions

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word for writing prose, or indeed poetry, under self-imposed restrictions such as only using one vowel, or maximum word length, or only on initial character (such as the poem *[On Thriftiness](http://alliterationpoemsforu2011.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/on-thriftiness/)*)

What is that word, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **[constrained writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing)**.

Comment: Hmmm. Would my daughter texting with a phone with a broken `m` key count? :-)

Comment: Thank you... the word I couldn't recall was Lipogram, but that link is much broader and much more helpful.

Comment: @Dancrumb: I know it more readily as Oulipo, so the English term just didn't sounds right at first. But it is conveniently transparent.